# How to read and check file contents in C++?

Tags: c++

I am now solving a C++ problem that I can enter a exist name in a file and then program check the corresponding password. I write the mainly code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
class user {
public:
    int password;
    char name[20];
};
int main()
{
    user c;
    char str[20];
    int password;
    int password2;
    int password3;

    ifstream fin("pwb.txt", ios::in);

    cout << "please enter your username: " << endl;
    cin >> str;

    while (fin >> c.name >> c.password) {
        if (strcmp(str, c.name) == 0) //login successfully
        {
            cout << "please enter your password: " << endl;
            cin >> password;
            if (c.password == password) {
                cout << "Welcome to phone Organizer!\n" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (c.password != password) {
                cout << "Wrong password!" << endl;
                cout << "enter again!: ";

                cin >> password2;
                if (c.password == password2) {
                    cout << "Welcome to phone Organizer!\n" << endl;
                    break;
                }
                else if (c.password != password2) {
                    cout << "Wrong password!" << endl;
                    cout << "enter again!: ";
                    cin >> password3;
                    {
                        if (c.password == password3) {
                            cout << "Welcome to phone Organizer!\n" << endl;
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            cout << "Wrong! Fail to login! " << endl; //here to quit the system!
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else if (strcmp(str, c.name) != 0) {
            cout << "your password: ";
            char fname[] = "pwb.txt";
            ofstream fin2(fname, ios::app);
            fin2 << '\n' << str << ' ';
            cin >> password;
            fin2 << password;
            fin2.close();
            cout << "Add successfully!";
            cout << "Welcome to phone Organizer!\n" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    fin.close();

    return 0;
}
```

AND THE content in the pwb.txt file is

Happy 123456

Sad 234567

Sorry 345678

I don't know why when I enter the Happy, then the program can work well; but when enter a existed Sad or Sorry, the program always doesn't check the existing contents and store the Sad one more time in the pwb.txt file. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand your description of the problem. Your code looks reasonable for this task. I assume your are not permitted to use `std::string` which is the proper string in `c++`. One potential problem is you never check if the file was opened. It may not exist in the current working directory so it may not be opened and you should probably issue an error message when that happens.

Comment: The else if  () {} part you should not open the same file name for writing while the other file is being read.

Comment: A non-`const` `int` is mutable so you can re-use the same `password` variable for each try. You don't need 3 different password variables.

Comment: ohhh! So how can I write the code when the input name is not exist and also add it into the same file?

Comment: It probably should do that after the while loop has checked all records. Probably before the while loop. Create a `bool found = false;` and set to true in the first line in your `login successfully` block. Then after the while loop close the file and if found is false ask for the information.

Comment: better to `memset to '\0'` both `user.name[]` and `str[]` char arrays

Comment: I try to move the writing file part out of while loop, but it seems that the str I input just fulfil both two if statements :(

Comment: You would change `if (strcmp(str, c.name) != 0)  {` to `if (!found) {` when you move it out of the loop.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use `char` arrays or are you allowed to use proper `std::string`s?

Comment: not allow to use string :( i can only use char array to represent a string.

Comment: with the if(!found) method, I can add the non-existent name , but some bugs happen in the wrong input password, when I enter more than twice, the set new password will come out. how can I solve it? adding break? but seems not work....

Comment: You may want to update the code in the question and ask about the new problem. Since no one has written an answer updating the code is acceptable. If not you can delete this question and start with a fresh one. Thankfully no one downvoted you so you won't lose any rep or be penalized.

Comment: "_not allow to use string_" - Oh, ok. Perhaps it's a bit too early, but I suggest trying creating your own `string`-like class if you have some time to spare. It doesn't have to be particularly fancy to make your life much easier - and it's a great exercise. You can also use `std::string` as inspiration and just implement the most important parts.